# How can I convert Full-width number characters to Ascii in Golang?

Tags: go, unicode

How do I convert full width characters into ascii characters in golang. The input in my program is full width numbers and I need to run some computations on them, so I assume I have to write a convert function like below, Before I start mapping bytes and such I was wondering if this is indeed available in the standard go library

```
fullWidth:="１２３"
expected := "123"
func convert(input string) string {
// body
}

expected == convert(fullWidth)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`width.Transformer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/width#Transformer) of the [`golang.org/x/text`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text) package to do the transformation but the standard library does not have this functionality. `x/text` is one of many official sub-repositories which have weaker compatibility requirements (see [here](https://golang.org/pkg/#other)).

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/text/width"
)

func main() {
    s := "１２３"
    n := width.Narrow.String(s)
    fmt.Printf("%U: %s\n", []rune(s), s)
    fmt.Printf("%U: %s\n", []rune(n), n)
}
```

Comment: I have it working now, but curious why it doesn't that work in playground https://play.golang.org/p/ZXLbG7hDMw" prog.go:5:5: cannot find package "golang.org/x/text/width"

Comment: Because packages that are not in the standard library are not imported in the playground (security, keeping them up-to-date, space, ...)